# horizontal justify the content , irrespective of length

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="uci_container_four_boxes" style="border: 1px solid blue;overflow:auto; margin: 0px auto; position: relative;height: 129px; background: #E8ECF2; margin-left:25px;">
            <div class="uci_inner_box1" style="text-align:center; height: 127px; width: 290.5px; border: 1px solid #b3b3b3; background: #E8ECF2; float: left; position: relative; margin-right: 15px;">
                <img style="display: inline-block;margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top:5px; width: 37px; height: 37px; position: absolute;" src="/app/uci/img/search-user.svg" class="uci_close"> <br>
                <div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;line-height: 0.75em; position: absolute; margin-top: 35px; color: #004d99; letter-spacing: 1.02px; font-size: 67px; font-family: TimesNewRoman;">22</div> <br>
                <div style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;margin-top: 72px; line-height: 0.75em; position: absolute; color: black; letter-spacing: 1.02px; font-size: 17px; font-family: CiscoSansLight;" class="uci_users_heading">Attached Users</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

The img is center aligned, but the value 22 and the text start from center and extend to right. What I want is both, the number and text should be justified from left and right margin , irrespective of length

I tried a number of options like setting `margin: 0px auto`, `display: flex`, etc but I'm still unable to justify the content. Please ignore the inline css, it is purposefully done, will be moved to external file later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `position: absolute` with `margin-top` on the inner elements to align. Delete these lines and the `text-align: center;` will align the content vertically.

Hope this helps:

```
<div class="uci_container_four_boxes" style="border: 1px solid blue;overflow:auto; margin: 0px auto; position: relative;height: 129px; background: #E8ECF2; margin-left:25px;">
    <div class="uci_inner_box1" style="text-align:center; height: 127px; width: 290.5px; border: 1px solid #b3b3b3; background: #E8ECF2; float: left; position: relative; margin-right: 15px;">
        <img style="display: inline-block;margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top:5px; width: 37px; height: 37px;" src="/app/uci/img/search-user.svg" class="uci_close"> <br>
        <div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;line-height: 0.75em; color: #004d99; letter-spacing: 1.02px; font-size: 67px; font-family: TimesNewRoman;">22</div> <br>
        <div style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; line-height: 0.75em; color: black; letter-spacing: 1.02px; font-size: 17px; font-family: CiscoSansLight;" class="uci_users_heading">Attached Users</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that, the reason for absolute is , i need the img and the 2 div elements to remain within the outer div i.e. (uci_inner_box1). If i remove the absolute position , the contents move out of the box

Comment: @sk215 They remain look here: [https://jsfiddle.net/3qutkzwe/](https://jsfiddle.net/3qutkzwe/)

Comment: Thanks, it wokred, i did not see that you have removed the margin-top. thanks a lot, made my day :)